# NSMutableArray Add and Save Objects

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist

New to iOS and am stuck on one issue in regards to adding objects in NSMutable Array and displaying the array on another view within the App.  The data displays fine on other view in TableView, but when I add another item to the Array (using code below), it just replaces what was there, not adding to the array.

```
- (void) postArray {
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
[tableData addObject:favShot]; }

-(NSString *) saveFilePath {

NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE);
return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"]; }

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated: (UIApplication *) application  {
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tableData, nil];
[values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically: TRUE]; }

- (void)viewDidLoad  {

tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

if (fileExists)
{

    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
    tableData = [values mutable copy];
}

UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:myApp];

[super viewDidLoad];  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `postArray` you're creating an instance of `NSMutableArray`, then throwing it away (leaking it if you aren't using ARC). Then you're creating another instance of `NSMutableArray`. Then you're adding an object (favShot) to that second instance.

Next time you call `postArray` it's going to throw away your old array and create 2 new ones.

What you want to do is create the `tableData` instance when you create the controller instance, or when the view loads. Then, don't set `tableData = ...` as that will discard the old instance. Just add and remove objects.

**edit**

```
- (void) postArray {
[tableData addObject:favShot];
}

- (NSString *)saveFilePath {
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE);
return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[tableData writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically: TRUE];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad  {
NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

if (fileExists)
{
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
} else {
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
}

UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:myApp];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: So I moved it to the viewDidLoad and I am able to add more than one, which is a huge improvement.  However, when I go back to previous views and re-enter the view where I add again to the array, that previous saved array is gone.  What am I missing here?

Comment: By moving to the previous view (presumably presented in a navigation controller) you're throwing away the view (and controller) and then recreating them when you navigate back. You would need to do something like write the array contents to disk in viewWillDisappear and then reload it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: If I'm saving it to the .plist why wouldn't it be available when I come back to that view?  I've used the .plist to save Strings across views and that seems to work.

Comment: If you're only triggering the save on applicationDidEnterBackground then it won't save when you move between views. Your saveFilePath method also isn't very safe and could crash if there are less objects in the array than you expect.

Comment: I implemented the save to the viewWillDisapper.  I am stuck however on how to put it in viewDidLoad.  I used the same code as I used in viewDidUnload and it did not work.  thanks.

Comment: Please update the question to show the current code and expand the problem description. You aren't saving in viewDidLoad, you're reloading from the file.

Comment: Everywhere you're doing 'objectAtIndex:3' it's wrong. in 'saveFilePath' it should (probably) be 'objectAtIndex:0'. In viewDidLoad it should be 'tableData = [values mutableCopy];'

Comment: it compiles and run, but still does not load/save it.  I'm a little confused on the 'tableData = [values mutableCopy];' portion.  When did I create that mutable and whether it's correct?

Comment: When you read the data back in, you want to set it as the 'tableData' variable. It needs to be mutable so you can change it when the table view row is selected.

Comment: What does it and doesn't it do now and what debugging did you do?

Comment: Compiles and runs well, displays to new view.  Only when I go back to previous screens does it cause the data to be lost, therefore does not load back up.  Stuck... any suggestions on have best I could approach additional debugging?

Comment: Finally just figured this out, just added a if statement checking if array is nil, if nil then alloc.  solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated: (UIApplication *) application 
{
    NSString *filePath = [self saveFilePath];

    NSMutableArray *savedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (!savedArray) savedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    [savedArray addObject:tableData];

    [savedArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it saves but does not solve my issue with saving when I move from view to view